# Erro ao criar um arquivo com fopen

Tags: php, xampp, back-end, fopen

Ao tentar criar um arquivo no formato JSON com o `fopen` me é retornado um erro de permissão com a seguinte mensagem:

> Warning: fopen(/json/9.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\apil\Controllers\Classex.php on line 120

Como utilizo o sistema operacional Windows também já dei permissão na pasta que já deixei pré-criada, no entanto, o problema ainda persiste.

Permissão que dei a todos sobre o arquivo JSON pressionando o botão direito em cima do arquivo->Propriedades->Compartilhar:

[image: Permissão que dei a todos sobre o arquivo 'json' pressionando botão direito em cima do arquivo->Propriedades->Compartilhar]

O código que estou utilizando para realizar a criação do arquivo e posteriormente gravar os dados nele segue a seguir:

```
 protected function filejson($product_id, $account_id) {
    $file = array($account_id);

    $json = fopen("/json/" . $product_id . ".json", "w");
    fwrite($json, json_encode($file));
    fclose($json);
}
```

E realizo a chamada do método em outro método que está na mesma classe da seguinte forma:

```
 Classex::filejson($product_id, $this->getAccount_id());
```

Vale ressaltar que ambos os paramentos `$product_id` e `$account_id` possuem o conteúdo correto ou seja não estão nulos.

Estou utilizando o XAMPP no Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Primeiro, e importante:

Compartilhar não é permissão de pasta. Compartilhar é permissão para acessarem a pasta de outro PC (e modificarem seu fonte inclusive).

Permissão de pasta é clicando em Propriedades > Segurança

### Segundo:

Tem uma barra sobrando no começo do caminho, o `fopen` é em relação ao sistema de arquivos, e não à raiz do site:

```
$json = fopen("/json/" . $product_id . ".json", "w");
//             ^
```

Se quer caminho relativo ao arquivo executado, pode usar assim:

```
$json = fopen("json/" . $product_id . ".json", "w");
```

Ou assim:

```
$json = fopen("./json/" . $product_id . ".json", "w");
```

Mesmo assim, precisa ter certeza que está executando o script na pasta correta, e que nada anterior neste código mudou o diretório de trabalho.

Uma alternativa seria usar alguma variável de ambiente para produzir o caminho completo:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // Equivale ao "/" do site, dependendo 
                                   // do jeito que foi configurado o servidor
                                   // No seu caso vai retornar algo como: C:/xampp/htdocs

$json = fopen("$root/json/" . $product_id . ".json", "w");
```

Comment: Agradeço desde já pela atenção Bacco,
Mas o mesmo erro ainda persiste mesmo implementando $_SERVER , será que o erro pode se tratar de um problema no XAMPP?

Comment: Só para complementar meu último comentário , ao usar o $_SERVER basicamente ele me retorna o mesmo erro com o caminho exato do arquivo "fopen(C:/xampp/htdocs/json/14.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ..."

Comment: Provavelmente é erro no caminho, experimente o caminho completo para fins de teste no formato `$json = fopen('C:/xampp/htdocs/json/9.json')` para um JSON fixo e existente de teste. Aproveite e veja o log de erros se não tem nenhuma restrição de basedir ou similares

Comment: É certeza que o caminho é esse mesmo? Verificou as permissões de pasta para o usuário do servidor de páginas? O json não precisa existir, que o PHP cria, mas o caminho de pastas não.

Comment: Note que COMPARTILHAR não é permissão de pasta. Permissão de pasta é na parte de segurança.

Comment: Realizei novamente a verificação e realmente o caminho do arquivo estava procurando a pasta json na pasta htdocs sendo que o correto era o caminho `$root/apil/Controllers/json/`.
Muito obrigado pelo atenção Bacco!

Comment: Ainda bem que resolveu, só observe a questão do compartilhamento, desfaça ele pra não ter acesso indevido ao arquivo fonte pela rede

Comment: blz , estarei retornado para a configuração default.